# can't apply external CSS in Struts2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I have a Java web application with struts2 framework. in my `index.jsp` file, I link the CSS file, but it doesn't show in my page and `Error 404: not found` display in `Firebug`. I tested one application without Struts and everything is fine. but when i add struts2 library and config `struts.xml` and `web.xml` file, CSS doesn't display :(
here is my index.jsp:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Of course, I add `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` and tried `<s:url>` in href, but don't see any effect.
here is web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <display-name>HotelSystem</display-name>
            <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and here is part of my struts.xml:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index.jsp" class="Actions.Test">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

**Note:** `Action.Test` is a test action and always return SUCCESS.

Comment: Never write *I really need to solve this problem as soon as possible. Please anyone help me* again if you *really* want to solve problems quickly, or solve them at all...

Comment: With Firebug you can try opening the CSS from your generated HTML. Try, and look at the resultant path. It will be wrong, and you will discover how; you will probably need to add a slash before `styles/`.

Answer (score 0):

You should map the .css type in the web.xml file as following!

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>expires-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```